# copying arrays of references

Tags: java, arrays, reference

I was reading about copying arrays of references.

```
Object[] obj1 = {new Integer(11),
                   new StringBuffer("foobar"),
                   new Double(12.95)};

  Object[] obj2 =  new Object[obj1.length];
  for(int i = 0; i < obj1.length; i ++)
        obj2[i] = obj1[i];

  //this change to obj1 does NOT effect obj2.
  obj1[0] = new Integer(5);

  System.out.println(Arrays.toString(obj1));
  System.out.println(Arrays.toString(obj2));
  System.out.println();


  //this change to obj1 DOES effect obj2
  ((StringBuffer) obj1[1]).append('s');

  System.out.println(Arrays.toString(obj1));
  System.out.println(Arrays.toString(obj2));
```

both the arrays pointing to same elements, but altering element change the 2nd array in 2nd case not in the first case.Can someone explain me why doesn't it change 2nd array in first case here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
obj1[0] = new Integer(5);
```

Here you are assigning a reference to a new object to the first index of one of the arrays, so the first index of the other array keeps referring to a different object and is not affected.

```
((StringBuffer) obj1[1]).append('s');
```

Here you are changing the state of the object referenced by `obj1[1]`, which is the same object referenced by `obj2[1]`. Therefore both arrays are affected.

Answer (score 1):

In this first case, you are changing the same object (by calling the `append` method on it). In the second, you are replacing a reference with a different reference. The original array still points to the original reference, and thus, remains unchanged.

Answer (score 1):

Here

```
obj1[0] = new Integer(5);
```

you change the object referenced by the first element of obj1 .
Changing the object referenced by a reference doesn't apply change to other references which referenced this object.
So, now  the first element of two arrays doesn't refer the same object any longer.

Here :

```
((StringBuffer) obj1[1]).append('s');
```

The first element of the two arrays references always the same object.
You have changed the content of the object referenced. So all references on this object see the change.